# Graphics Generation showing errors during JMeter test execution

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to use the Graphics Generator in my test plan execution. I am using the GUI mode to test it first. But i am getting an error in the logs as below.

```
2017/03/07 10:11:06 WARN  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Error encountered during shutdown of kg.apc.jmeter.listener.GraphsGeneratorListener@447613cf java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.SynthesisReportGui
at kg.apc.jmeter.PluginsCMDWorker.getGUIObject(PluginsCMDWorker.java:237)
at kg.apc.jmeter.PluginsCMDWorker.getGUIObject(PluginsCMDWorker.java:234)
at kg.apc.jmeter.PluginsCMDWorker.setPluginType(PluginsCMDWorker.java:73)
at kg.apc.jmeter.listener.GraphsGeneratorListener.testEnded(GraphsGeneratorListener.java:221)
at kg.apc.jmeter.listener.GraphsGeneratorListener.testEnded(GraphsGeneratorListener.java:137)
at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfEnd(StandardJMeterEngine.java:216)
at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:437)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:   kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.SynthesisReportGui
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at kg.apc.jmeter.PluginsCMDWorker.getGUIObject(PluginsCMDWorker.java:227)
... 7 more
```

I am not sure why is this error. Can someone help me to fix this? Is there any way to get the Graphics Generator working in the command line mode. Also how to get other plugins like Transactions per second and Hits per second working in the same way in one shot. Please someone put some light into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the error you don't have [Synthesis Report](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SynthesisReport/) plugin installed, you need to add it to your JMeter installation either [manually](https://jmeter-plugins.org/?search=jpgc-synthesis) or using the [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager) (recommended way of installing JMeter plugins and keep them up-to-date)

[image: JMeter Synthesis Report JMeter Plugins Manager]

Comment: Excellent. I can see all the reports now but there is an error displayed here. Can you please check this?*****************************************************      2017/03/07 10:51:10 WARN  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Error encountered during shutdown of kg.apc.jmeter.listener.GraphsGeneratorListener@3635d335 java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.ResponseTimesDistributionGui    ... Also is there any way to get all these details in PNG using command line?

Comment: Ok. I found it. @Dmitri Thanks for the help. Is there any way to get the Dashboard and Graphics Generator generating all the PNGs from the same result file?